# Проблема с настройкой IIS UrlRewrite для ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, миграция

Мигрирую старый проект c `asp net core 2.2` на `asp net core 3.1`. В качестве frontend используется `Angular`. Вот рабочий код `.net core 2.2`, который подключает правила UrlRewrite для IIS. Код из класса `Startup`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    ConfigureUrlRewriting(app, env);
    ConfigureRouting(app);
}

private static void ConfigureUrlRewriting(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment() && File.Exists("IISUrlRewrite.xml"))
    {
        using (var reader = File.OpenText("IISUrlRewrite.xml"))
        {
            var options = new RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite(reader);
            app.UseRewriter(options);
        }
    }
}

private static void ConfigureRouting(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
    {
        DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html" }
    });
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "api/{controller}/{id}");
    });
}
```

После миграции на `.net core 3.1` по [гайду от Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) код не сильно изменился:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    ConfigureUrlRewriting(app, env);
    ConfigureRouting(app);
}


private static void ConfigureUrlRewriting(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment() && File.Exists("IISUrlRewrite.xml"))
    {
        using (var reader = File.OpenText("IISUrlRewrite.xml"))
        {
            var options = new RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite(reader);
            app.UseRewriter(options);
        }
    }
}

private static void ConfigureRouting(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
    {
        DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html" }
    });
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    // Изменилось только то, что ниже
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "api/{controller}/{id}");
    });
}
```

Файл `index.html` браузер возвращает, но все статические файлы почему-то не находятся. Вместо них возвращается `index.html`. Вот доказательство:

[image: static-file-as-index-html]

Из [документации майкрософта для UrlRewrite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1) понятно, что добавление middleware `AddRewriter(rewriter)` должно происходить до `AddStaticFiles()`.
Не понимаю, что могло поменяться в .net core, что такая последовательность добавления middleware могла перестать работать как ожидается. В чем может быть дело? Уже сижу двое суток, борюсь с этой проблемой. Может быть, для .net core 3.1 используется какой-то другой IIS модуль и синтаксис xml поменялся?

На всякий случай, добавлю содержимое файла `IISUrlRewrite.xml`:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)/" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читая раздел [When to use URL Rewriting Middleware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1#when-to-use-url-rewriting-middleware) из документации Microsoft по `UrlRewrite Middleware` был неприятно удивлен. Оказывается, что `UrlRewrite Middleware` не поддерживает `IsFile` и `IsDirectory` ограничения. Цитата:

> The main reasons to use the server-based URL rewriting technologies in
> IIS, Apache, and Nginx are:
>
> The middleware doesn't support the full features of these modules.
>
> Some of the features of the server modules don't work with ASP.NET
> Core projects, such as the **IsFile** and **IsDirectory** constraints of the
> IIS Rewrite module. In these scenarios, use the middleware instead.

Поэтому в моем случае эти условия не срабатывают

```
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
```

Из-за чего вместо статических файлов мне возвращается `index.html`. Что самое интересное -- с уже устаревшей версией `ASP.NET Core 2.2` эти правила на статические файлы и директории работают. Получается, при переходе на Generic Host что-то очень сильно поменялось, из-за чего Microsoft решили отказаться от поддержки `IsFile` и `IsDirectory`

В итоге решил отказаться от этого Middleware и буду настраивать `UrlRewrite` на самом сервере

Comment: А зачем вам вообще устаревший UrlRewrite и чем не угодили нормальные маршруты?

Comment: Тот же `MapSpaFallbackRoute`, или просто какой-нибудь велосипед в самом конце цепочки?

Comment: @PavelMayorov у нас приложение деплоится на Linux, уже давно было принято решение переложить ответственность UrlRewrite на nginx. Для локального дебага на IIS нужна была альтернатива, которой являлся `IIS Url Rewrite middleware`. Менять конфигурацию nginx только ради локального дебага не очень хотелось бы. Буду разворачивать у себя приложение в docker контейнере

Comment: Если вы используете nginx - то **IIS** Url Rewrite вам тем более не в тему.

Comment: И да, в nginx тоже не обязательно использовать rewrite, там тоже свои маршруты (location) есть!

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, именно так у нас и реализовано. Я неправильно выразился

Answer (score 2):

Зачем вообще нужен UrlRewrite? Попытка написания логики в XML-файле при наличии под рукой нормального языка программирования выглядит странно. Вот как подобное делается без UrlRewrite:

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles();

// Если мы дошли до сюда - значит, запрос уже не соответствует ни одному реальному файлу

app.UseRouting();

app.MapWhen(
    ctx => ctx.GetEndpoint() == null, // Если для запроса не найден маршрут…
    app2 => app2.Use((ctx, next) =>
    {
        ctx.Request.Path = "/index.html"; // …то переписываем URL запроса…
        return next();
    })
    .UseStaticFiles() // …и даём ещё один шанс UseStaticFiles
);

app.UseEndpoints(…);
```

Также вместо MapWhen можно просто перенести всю обработку (это выглядит проще, но при добавлении авторизации поломается):

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles();

// Если мы дошли до сюда - значит, запрос уже не соответствует ни одному реальному файлу

app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(…);

// Если мы дошли до сюда - значит, для запроса не найден маршрут

app.Use((ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.Path = "/index.html";
    return next();
})
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Comment: Я чуть позже отпишусь. Сходу ваше решение у меня не заработало. Пока нет времени подробно смотреть, почему не сработало

Comment: @AndreiKhotko я его проверял, так что работать оно должно.

Comment: Да, оно работает. Спасибо за помощь! У меня была еще одна проблема после перехода, из-за чего ваш код не работал, но потом поправил, и все стало как надо